# Not able to find a document When I insert a Ensure index query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

1. I Create a document `db.duplicate.ensureIndex ({"a": 1}, {"unique": "true"})`
2. To create a unique index on `a`
3. When I search for the document I don't find the a value (`db.duplicate.find()`)
4. Ideally it should create a document with `_id &  a = 1` ? Is this approach right?

Answer (score 1):

The `ensureIndex` function creates an [index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) for the collection, not a [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/). This is to increase the performance when querying for documents with `a` as the index.

For creating documents, try with [insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/):

```
db.duplicate.insert({'a': 1})
```